# "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError" when printing json file dictionary in python script

Tags: python, json

My JSON file looks like this with filename as constants.json:

```
[
    {
        "PK": "abc",
        "SK": "def",
        "label": "eee",
        "value": "fgh",
        
    }
]
```

To read and print this in my python file, I used this code:

```
import json

     
with open('constants.json') as file1:
    data=json.load(file1)
for item in data:
    print(item)
```

I am getting an error when running the python file in visual studio code

```
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 296, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
>>> for item in data:
...     print(item)
```

Comment: You forgot the ending brace to the square bracket, as defined at the start of the JSON.

Comment: Only here where i tried to post, but in my script it's there

Comment: The error is unrelated to VS Code because it's just an IDE it isn't actually the one parsing your JSON. You'll get the same error outside VS Code. You can check if your JSON is valid by posting it at https://jsonlint.com/.

Answer (score 1):

When you receive this kind of error:

```
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Your first instinct should be to check if the JSON is valid, because that error means Python's `json` decoder couldn't parse your JSON file properly. One way to validate your JSON file is to post it on https://jsonlint.com/, and posting that constants.json would show up with this error:

```
Error: Parse error on line 5:
...,    "value": "fgh",}]
--------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', got '}'
```

The error is a bit cryptic, but that site offers some hints at the bottom of the page:

> #### Common Errors
>
> - Expecting `'STRING'` - You probably have an extra comma at the end of your collection. Something like `{ "a": "b", }`
> - Expecting `'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['` - You probably have an extra comma at the end of your list. Something
>   like: `["a", "b", ]`

And as [llamaking136 pointed out in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66285178/2745495), the error is from the trailing comma after `"fgh",`.

Since you also mentioned Visual Studio Code, the IDE provides [built-in linting of your JSON files](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json#_intellisense-and-validation), and if there are any errors, it will shows up with red squiggly lines and display a list of errors on the **Problems** tab:

[image]

So you can see and resolve the problem *even before running any code*.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your JSON, line 6.

The dictionary ends with a comma, and the JSON interpreter expects another value after that, but it reaches the end before it can find it.

```json
[
    {
        "PK": "abc",
        "SK": "def",
        "label": "eee",
        "value": "fgh"
    }
]
```